# How to align a horizontal list to the center in css

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I'm attempting to learn some things about css and html, and I'm currently playing with webpage menus.

I've been using this website: (http://www.cssportal.com/css3-menu-generator/) to play with stuff visually and infer the syntax by how the code elements are changing however, this generator is missing a feature I want to understand: Aligning the list horizontally.

how could the output of this generator be edited so that the buttons are aligned with the center of the menu bar instead of the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of floating the `li`s, you can set them to `display: inline-block`:

```
.menu {text-align: center;}
.menu > li {display: inline-block;}
```